# How to pass a string as argument JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to pass some HTML code as String in a Javascript function but it keeps-on being executed as HTML code and not as a parameter, even by putting the quotes to delimit it as a string.

The navigator reads the string not as parameter but as HTML code.

It's the function cancelVolet() inside the img tag, 4th line:

```
function editVoletVisual(r){
    var x = new String(r.parentNode.parentNode.innerHTML);
    var y = x.replace('"','\"');
    r.parentNode.innerHTML="<input name=\"edtVolet\" type=\"text\" id=\"edtVolet\"><img src=\"ressources/images/dlt.png\" align=\"top\" id=\"canceler\" onclick=\"cancelVolet(\""+y+"\")\">";
}
```

Here is the problem:
On clicking on the Edit Button (image with paper and pen)
[image: before]

The Yellow highlighted part is supposed to be a parameter, not HTML code to be showed!
[image: after]

How can I solve this problem, please help?

Comment: What program is this?

Comment: You know you can make things a little easier by putting the string in single quotes and then you wouldn't have to escape all those double quotes.

Comment: @Andy I know and it didn't solve anything.

Comment: @evolutionxbox a JEE web app I'm creating.

Comment: You need some kind of `htmlentities` function to convert `< > & "` to entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one of the solutions, is to use the `encodeURI` function

```
r.parentNode.innerHTML= "<input ... onclick=\"cancelVolet(\""+encodeURI(y)+"\")\">"
```

and inside the `cancelVolet` function, use `decodeURI` to get your parameter as it should be

```
function cancelVolet (param) {
   param = decodeURI (param);
   /* Your code here */
}
```

> `escape` and `unescape` can do the same job but [they are deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/escape).

Comment: Thank you very much, that was a great solution! Just the \" shoul be \'. Otherwise, it will be written as end of onclick="cancelVolet"

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem comes from double double-quotes.

```
onclick=\"cancelVolet(\""+y+"\")\">
```

This becomes

```
onclick="cancelVolet("{the value of y}")">
```

The onclick will just contain `cancelvolet(` the rest will be displayed.
Try with

```
onclick=\"cancelVolet(\'"+y+"\')\">
```

so that your browser will interpret this as

```
onclick="cancelVolet('{the value of y}')">
```